# Google Maps API Loads Google Logo But No Map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working with a code base that was written about 2 years ago (so I am wondering if something on the API end changed causing this issue). It is also known to have worked 2 years ago, so I can't imagine it is a problem with the code itself... I think I am just not setting up the API correctly.

Anyway, I have Google Maps API creating a map inside of a Fragment. I have created a new API key and believe to have followed those instructions for setting up a new key correctly. Whenever I run the application, the Google logo loads in the bottom left corner of the fragment. This indicates to me that there is some amount of communication happening with the API. However, no map shows up. Only a beige screen.

I have tried going back through the API setup process several times and have not had much luck. After reading other posts indicating some changes in the AndroidManifest.xml, I tried changing the information stored in the  tags, but that did not change anything.

MapViewFragment.java

```java
public class MapViewFragment extends Fragment {

    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    final int MY_MAPS_REQUEST = 31415;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_view, container, false);

        mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        //final ImageButton returnButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.returnLocationButton);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                googleMap = mMap;
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
                // For showing a move to my location button
                /*String[] permissionRequests = new String[1];
                permissionRequests[0] = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),permissionRequests,0);*/
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Should we show an explanation?
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {

                        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                    } else {
                        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                                MY_MAPS_REQUEST);

                        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                        // result of the request.
                    }
                }
                else{
                    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

                /* some points dropped here, but removed because its not relevant */ 


                // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
                final CameraPosition cameraPositionWetlands = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(centerPoint).zoom(15).build();
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPositionWetlands));
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_MAPS_REQUEST: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay!
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }
                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(mMapView != null) {
            mMapView.onResume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(mMapView != null) {
            mMapView.onPause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(mMapView != null) {
            mMapView.onDestroy();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        if(mMapView != null) {
            mMapView.onLowMemory();
        }
    }
}
```

map_view.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".MapViewFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/returnLocationButton"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_return_location" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

google_maps_api.xml

```xml
<resources>
    <!--
    TODO: Before you run your application, you need a Google Maps API key.

    To get one, follow this link, follow the directions and press "Create" at the end:


    You can also add your credentials to an existing key, using these values:

    Package name:
    ***
    SHA-1 certificate fingerprint:
    ***

    Alternatively, follow the directions here:
    https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get-key

    Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
    string in this file.
    -->
    <string name="google_maps_key" translatable="false">AIza************************************</string>
</resources>
```

UPDATE: Just found this stack trace hidden in my run-time console.

```
E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
    Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
    Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
        API Key: AIza***********************************
        Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): cert:finger:print;com.project.name
```

Comment: in a new project, if you start a new maps activity; does that work?  if it does, I would compare the two.  I know thats not an answer, but that is what I would do.

Comment: Follow [these](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup#detailed_guide) steps to get an API key